# Why am i having a printformat error?

Tags: java

so this is the    code i have written and i am not sure where the error is so maybe you guys can help..

```
import java.util.Scanner;



public class Discount {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("please enter price(1) ");
        double price1=input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("please enter price(2) ");
        double price2=input.nextDouble();
        double discounted1=(1/3)*price1;
        double discounted2=(1/3)*price2;
        int eq1=(int)(discounted1*1508);
        int eq2=(int)(discounted2*1508);
        int w1;
        int w2;
        int w3;
        String f=discounted1+"";
        String d=discounted2+"";
        String i=price1+"";
        String s=price2+"";
        String a=eq1+"";
        String b=eq2+"";

        if(price1>price2){
            w1=i.length();
            w2=f.length();
            w3=a.length();
        }
        else{
            w1=s.length();
            w2=d.length();
            w3=b.length();


        }

        System.out.println("Price(in USD) \tDiscounted\tEquivalent Price (in LL)");
        System.out.printf("$%w1f\t$%w2f\tLL%w3d\n", price1,discounted1,eq1);
        System.out.printf("$%w1f\t$%w2f\tLL%w3d\n", price2,discounted2,eq2);

    }
}
```

the error it gives me is Exception in thread "main":

```
    java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'w'
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.conversion(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintStream.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintStream.printf(Unknown Source)
    at Discount.main(Discount.java:40)
```

Comment: `w` isn't a valid format specifier. Like it says in the message. Valid format specifiers [are described in the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).